# En la frase "I would like pizza instead of pasta" en español, ¿debo usar "gustaría" o "gusta"?

Tags: traducción, tiempos-verbales

Estoy tratando de decir:

> I would like pizza instead of pasta

en español.

¿Qué forma de *gustar* es correcta, *"Me Gustaría"* o *"Me Gusta"*?

> Me **gusta** pizza en vez de pasta.

o

> Me **gustaría** pizza en vez de pasta.

Let me apologize for my very poor Spanish, I am very new to the language

Comment: There is no need to apologize for the use of Spanish. On the contrary, we really appreciate your efforts to use our language and thank you for that. :-) Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a formal context, the following sentence sounds more natural to me:

> Quisiera pizza en vez de pasta.

In a more informal situation, if you choose to use "me gustaría", don't forget to put the accent mark on the "i".

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta! Gracias y bienvenida a [spanish.se]

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: También sería correcto usar el condicional *querría*. Curiosamente, ha surgido últimamente el tema de la alternancia condicional/subjuntivo en la página. Puedes echarle un ojo al debate en las tres últimas preguntas de [Aurora](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12888/aurora)

Answer (score 3):

Por usar un verbo diferente, yo propondría:

> **Prefiero** pizza en vez de pasta.

o

> **Preferiría** pizza en vez de pasta.

siendo la segunda opción más formal (como se ha comentado en otras respuestas).

Cuando eliges una opción por encima de otra porque te gusta más o por el motivo que sea, se suele usar el verbo *preferir*.

Answer (score 2):

Decir

> Me **gusta** una pizza,

corresponde a un estado permanente. (El uso del artículo indefinido muestra que no se sabe qué tipo de pizza.)

Mientras que,

> Me *gustaría* una pizza,

es lo que comúnmente se usa para la cortesía con *would like*.

Por tanto, *I would like* simplemente corresponde a *me gustaría*.
En todo caso, se acostumbra bastante a poner *quisiera*, así que las dos formas son válidas.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Qué forma de gustar es correcta, "Me Gustaría" o "Me Gusta"?

Si en inglés aparece el verbo modal "would", conjuga el verbo en tiempo **condicional simple**.

> I **would** like to drive
>   <sub>= Me **gustaría** conducir</sub>
>
> I like pizza
>   <sub>= Me **gusta** la pizza</sub>

(La única excepción sería "would have [verb]", que se traduciría como condicional compuesto, p.ej. «I would have gone myself» = «Hubiera ido yo mismo»)

De manera análoga, el verbo modal "will" cambia el tiempo verbal a futuro.

Comment: *would have gone* es en realidad *habría ido.*

Comment: Tienes razón. Supongo que en algunos casos también se pueden usar tiempos de subjuntivo.